# What is the right approach to set up modules in Zend Framework 1 based application

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-modules

Hi guys I'm a bit confused on how to use modules within my Zend Framework based application - from what I've read up on modules work as sub application within your application however where does the line blur between what goes into a module and what can be handled within the controller. Like for example in a Home booking application you have the following features:

House management
Rate Management
Booking online + booking management

Consider that we have three types of users an admin user, a customer who makes the booking and a landlord who owns a house set up for booking how would be set up our modules i.e would we have something like:

```
admin
->controllers
  ->houseController
  ->rateController
  ->bookingController
  ->customersController
landlord
->controllers
  ->houseController
  ->rateController
  ->bookingController
customer
->controllers
  ->bookingController
```

or would it be something like:

```
modules
->Booking
->Rate
->Customers
```

The latter format seems a bit like turning controllers into modules - whats the right approach here?

In the original listings - there are repeated controllers in each module. Pretty much the difference is quite minute eg: houseController for instance in admin module - administrators can view all houses by all landlords while landlords can view only their own houses. Technically I'm repeating 90% of the code here which doesn't seem like the right thing to do as I don't think you can use ACL to restrict the listings that can be viewed. What is the right approach here for this logic?

Answer (score 1):

ok. let's try to answer it...

this is a classical optimization challenge (regarding the application architecture). based on what your goal is, you will have different optimization approaches. I prefer to optimize application architecture regarding resulting technical functionality. if the functionality of your desired modules

- admin
- landlord
- customer

have different functionality scopes, keep them separated (this will also simplify ACL definition).

based on what you have posted in your question there is some controller "overlapping":

- houseController
- rateController
- bookingController

they are used multiple times. functionality wise, they should be used only in one module. if you can not separate them, there is no need for separate modules...

hope this gives you an overview on how to use modules.

Comment: I'd also probably also push most of the models up to application-level since they will probably be used across all modules.

Comment: Well the reason why they seem to be repeated is because each of the users have a different view eg: The administrator can view all homes by all houseowners while houseowners can view only their own homes. This is pretty much the only difference here and it seems a bit like overkill to repeat almost 90% of the controller and views here. Is this the right way to handle this logic?

Comment: just a general remark: if you have to repeat, your architecture is not right yet. in this case you would handle this in the model. based on access rights, you retrieve more or less data...

Comment: Makes sense to have it in the model - whats the best way to actually accomplish this - do I pass in the id of the user logged in from teh controller or do I set up the model to access the session object?

Comment: depending on your data model you have to pass all atributes with which you are able to "restrict" the SQL query to be able to provide the desired functionality. "id" could be one of them. you probably also need to pass a "user role" attribute to be able to refine SQL query composition...

Comment: Sorry was off the radar for a while - I'd like to see a simple example of a good practice to implement something like this - Basically my question was is it better to do all the checking for the users access rights in the controller or in the model like from the controller do I pass parameters based on logged in user to model or does the model access the users session object and the controller has little to no say - whats a better way?

Answer (score 1):

it looks to me as if most of this functionality would be more appropriate to the models. you might be able to get away with just the default module with a property controller with different views for customers and owners with maybe a separate module for the admin as admins usually have more functionality required for management.

```
//bare minimum, you may need to add controllers andd models for user/owner objects and rate managment
/application
    /controllers
        /IndexController // default entry to application, login, authentication
        /ErrorController
        /PropertyController // actions to view, book and reserve a property object, may provide some extra functions for owners.
    /modules
        /admin
            /IndexController // provides actions for administration activities such as managing user and owners and setting ACL and Authentication.
```

This is just my opinion, keep in mind that modules in ZF1 are a completely different animal from modules in ZF2.

Comment: I agree however in this application almost all types of users have similar functionalities - the only difference is in the level of access eg: Admin access all data while users access only their own data.

Answer (score 0):

While the question is old I feel it still hasn't been answered. I myself have been setting up an e-commerce CMS project for the last few days and learning the basics of Zend Framework coming from a silver light Prism background. One thing that I can suggest is to understand that a module doesn't need to be small. The very definition of a module is "An independent self-contained unit" so in your case you'll have a "BookingModule" that when finished should be able to be chucked into any application and then with the proper tie ins can communicate with other modules. The issue with your layout is your relying on the modules to separate your different levels of access (which in a reply you basically ask "how should I do this"), what you want todo is use some sort of Authentication method to see if the current user can run a specific action. Off what you've given us I'd suggest a role based authentication method with maybe multiple actions (still deciding this part for myself).

Zend Framework

- Hosts an "Application" which contain modules that utilize MVC

Module

- An independent self-contained unit that can be plugged into any application
- Can have hooks/tie-ins to communicate to other modules within an application

MVC

- Models: Insure Data integrity through Validation verification
- Views: Displays the Model's Data to the user
- Controllers: Process user input through Actions that edit Data

  - Action: Security logic should go here, to ensure the user can use this action.

Role

- An Enum for use in Authentication

**TL;DR**
For your project you should have 1 module, 4 controllers, 3 roles and an authorization Service tied to your controller's actions to verify the current user can run said action. This'll prevent repeating code and also allow it to be expandable without any code rewrites.

Read this to understand Authorization on Actions:
[Activity based checks](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/)

Edit:
Should probably note that there is nothing wrong with making each one a module as it is workable, its just more work to tie in and more coding with the only gain being you could pull say the Bookings Module into a completely different Application without the need for the other 2. But from my understanding you just want 1 module